# Script not executing output

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im working on switching from python to javascript, not going quite so easily... I think I have nested everything properly, I made sure the inputs were matched to the variables and that the submission was linked to the function, I don not see syntax errors according to my knowledge, but I am just beginning my quest to grapple with javascript. Please help to understand the issues, I do not expect anyone to rewrite the whole thing, I will be doing any research to what ever problems are debugged.

```js
function loanQualify() {
  let loan_size = parseInt(document.getElementById('loanBox').value);
  let credit_history = parseInt(document.getElementById('creditBox').value);
  let income_size = parseInt(document.getElementById('incomeBox').value);
  let down_payment_size = parseInt(document.getElementById('paymentBox').value);
  let qualify;
  if (loan_size >= 5) {
    if (credit_history >= 7 && income_size >= 7)
      qualify == true;
    else if (credit_history >= 7 || income_size >= 7) {
      if (down_payment_size >= 5)
        qualify == true;
      else
        qualify == false;
    } else
      qualify == false;
  } else {
    if (credit_history < 4)
      qualify == false;
    else {
      if (income_size >= 7 || down_payment_size >= 7)
        qualify = true;
      else if (income_size >= 4 && down_payment_size >= 4)
        qualify == true;
      else
        qualify == false;
    }
  }

}

if (qualify == true)
  document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You qualify";
else(qualify == false)
document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You don't qualify";
```

```html
Loan Size: <input type="text" id="loanBox" size="3"><br> Credit History: <input type="text" id="creditBox" size="3"><br> Income Size: <input type="text" id="incomeBox" size="3"><br> Down Payment Size: <input type="text" id="paymentBox" size="3"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loanQualify()">Qualify?</button>

<div id="trueFalse"></div>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket somewhere. Also equality comparison is done by `==` or `===`.  A single `=` is for assignment.

Comment: One thing to point out is you're assigning in the if statements... `if (qualify = true)` should be `if (qualify == true)` or just `if (qualify)`

Comment: how would I implement a case statement considering the nested if statements? Would I need more than one switch statement?

Comment: You are missing close to the function.

Comment: I think I did what you all stated but it still wont run

Comment: @NickDuPlessis check out my answer you cannot assign a condition in `else()` statement.

Comment: The biggest issue as far as I can tell is `=` versus `==`. The former is used to assign, just like in Python. `==` is used to compare, exactly like with Python. Also note that JavaScript is very good. For instance you can do `qualify = down_payment_size >= 5;` where JS will evaluate the comparison on the right to `true` or `false` and assign the result to `qualify` (...exactly like you can do in Python)

Comment: Also it seems that the missing bracket you added is not added in the right place. The part that assigns the text to the element is outside of your function right now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a condition in else and your `if()` must have `==` which  checks the condition.

```
if (qualify = true)
document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You qualify";
else (qualify = false)
document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You don't qualify";
```

**Change it to**

```
if (qualify == true)
  document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You qualify";
else
  document.getElementById('trueFalse').innerHTML = "You don't qualify";
```

Comment: Please remove the downvotes if the person has corrected the post.

Comment: Your "Change it to" function has a syntax error. Not to mention that simply changing that code (even without the syntax error) will still not work for OP.